# Using @PathVariable with Parent ID to Save Child over REST

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, http-post

Spring Boot, I have a Rest Controller where I'm trying to save a an object with a parent.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference()
    private List<Child> children;

  // getters / setters
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonView(Views.Summary.class)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    @NotNull
    @JsonBackReference()
    private Parent parent;

   // getters / setters
}
```

Because of the `@JsonBackReference`, Jackson won't serialize the Child object fully including the Parent. So doing something like the following in my test doesn't work...

```
Child child = new Child()
child.setParent(parent)

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
String payload = mapper.writeValueAsString(child);
```

I end up with the following JSON:

```
{ "id": null }
```

Where what I really would want is

```
{ "id": null, parent: { "id": 1 } }
```

So what I decided to do was add the parent id as a `@PathVariable` and just pass that into my service method, and set it manually. The problem is that since `Parent` cannot be null in Child, and I'm validating the Child using `@Valid` I don't even get into the crux of my method so that I can deal with the Parent ID.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{parentId}/children", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void save(@PathVariable Long parentId, @Valid @RequestBody Child child, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            throw new InvalidRequestException("Invalid Child", bindingResult);
        }

        this.storeService.save(parentId, child);
        response.setHeader("Location", request.getRequestURL().append("/").append(child.getId()).toString());
    }
```

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: What I've done for now is removed the `@NotNull` annotation and added `nullable = false` to `@ManyToOne`. This allows the initial validation to pass but still creates the constraint on the database. While this works, I'd still be curious to know alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JPA model (as you wrote it) says that the `Parent` object contains a list of `Child` objects. Furthermore, the use of `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` says that this is the `Parent` object that should manage the `Child` objects, not the other way around.

In other words, if you want to save your data, you need to:

- get or create the `Parent` object (Ok)
- create a `Child` object (Ok)
- set the child's parent (Ok)
- add the child to the parent <-- You're missing this part and the next one
- save the parent (and not the child directly)

Every time you need to update the children, do the modification in the parent, then save the parent.

This is why this is irrelevant to have the parent's id in the serialised child.

Also, I would suggest that you add the `orphanRemoval=true` to your `@OneToMany` annotation, so that children not linked anymore to their parent should be deleted as well

**UPDATE (to clarify)**:
If you're using a cascade (and even more if it's cascade ALL), you don't tell your application that you want to update a `Child`instance. What you do is update the child in its parent, then save the parent. The cascading will do the rest.

Comment: So with this approach, are you saying that a `ParentService` should contain some sort of `addChild` method vs calling a `ChildService.save()`?

Comment: Also, this does't really answer my question as the `ChildController` seems the appropriate place to do stuff with a Child even if it belongs to a Parent. It's the validation that I was struggling with more than the explanation of why having the Parent serialized in the Child wasn't necessary. I do appreciate the help though.

Comment: What I'm saying is that in this case, you don't need a `ChildService`, because everything should be managed through the `Parent` object, through the `ParentService`. The `ParentService` will proxy the `ParentRepository` calls (CRUD). But you don't need an `addChild()` method in the service. You only have to do a `parent.getChildren().add(child)` call, then save the parent. The cascading will take care of the rest.

Comment: And for your second comment, my point is that the `ChildController` shouldn't do that kind of thing either. You should use a `ParentController` instead, then. That said, I'm telling you that because of the cascading strategy you chose, which is a totally valid approach.

Comment: Thanks. That all makes sense. I'm just trying to get it to gel with a RESTful API and what the endpoints will look like. for example POST: `/api/parents/1/children` would actually call the ParentController? That's where I'm a little disconnected based on your comments.

Comment: I realize this is going beyond the question, so maybe this would be better as a chat room.

Comment: POST on /api/parents to create, and PUT on /api/parents/1 to update. The point is you don't need to "tell" the application you want to update a child. What you want to update, is the parent, which happens to have a child to update (event if the parent itself - i.e. its children left aside - as no changed properties). I'll update my answer with this remark.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111256/discussion-between-gregg-and-alexandre-fillatre).